# How to make reverse proxy?

Tags: go, reverse-proxy

I have a server written in Go. I want to write for it a reverse proxy server.  The server is compiled into one binary file.  When I try to access it through a proxy server, it returns only the HTML page without bindings to CSS and JS scripts. How can I organize the transfer of static files?

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httputil"
    "net/url"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    u1, _ := url.Parse("http://localhost:8080/")
    proxy := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(u1)
    mux.Handle("/app1", proxy)

    serv := &http.Server{
        Addr:           ":9090",
        ReadTimeout:    10 * time.Second,
        WriteTimeout:   10 * time.Second,
        Handler:        mux,
    }

    err := serv.ListenAndServe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ListenAndServe: ", err)
    }

}
```

Comment: `mux.Handle("/app1", proxy)` handles only the exact path `"/app1"`. To also handle things like `"/app1/style.css"`, register the path `"/app1/"` (with trailing slash), [as documented](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeMux).

Comment: You may want to check [this tutorial](https://medium.com/ymedialabs-innovation/reverse-proxy-in-go-d26482acbcad) for more comprehensive example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing a reverse proxy is a complex task. If you plan to expose it on the public internet, I suggest to use an existing one, e.g. [Caddyserver](https://caddyserver.com/), which is written in Go and still free if you compile it yourself instead of using the pre-compiled binaries. The [source code of Caddyserver](https://github.com/mholt/caddy) can also give you ideas how to implement it on your own, if you still want to pursue that idea.

To your more specific question about serving files: This can be done with the http.ServeFile method or easier with [httprouter's](https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter) ServeFiles or FileServer methods. See https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter#static-files.

Comment: The OP is already using golang's native `httputil.ReverseProxy`. Its source is a much more reliable/maintained place to learn from: https://golang.org/src/net/http/httputil/reverseproxy.go